# How to get text from PDF file with AWS Textract

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-textract

I have pdf url:

```
pdf_url = "https://www.buelach.ch/fileadmin/files/documents/Finanzen/Bericht_zum_Budget_2023.pdf"
```

I want to extract text from that file. Important thing is that I do not want to save it on my computer or on S3, I want to do it directly from link.

My full code:

```
import boto3
import requests

# Specify the URL of the PDF file
pdf_url = "https://www.buelach.ch/fileadmin/files/documents/Finanzen/Bericht_zum_Budget_2023.pdf"
print("Get URL")

# Send a request to the PDF file and get the response as a bytearray
response = requests.get(pdf_url)
pdf_data = bytearray(response.content)
print("Get response", response)


# Create a boto3 session and Textract client
session = boto3.Session()
textract = session.client("textract")
print("Created textract")


# Call Textract to detect the text in the PDF
response = textract.detect_document_text(Document={"Bytes": pdf_data})
print("Get textract response")

# Extract the text from the response
text = ""
for block in response["Blocks"]:
    if block["BlockType"] == "LINE":
        text += block["Text"] + "\n"

print(text)
```

I am getting this error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.UnsupportedDocumentException: An error occurred (UnsupportedDocumentException) when calling the DetectDocumentText operation: Request has unsupported document format
```

Any help?

I have tried to make it work with:

```
pdf_data = bytearray(response.content)
```

and

```
pdf_data = response.content
```

But I am getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You are using a synchronous operation, and in that case it only supports PNG or JPEG images.  Doing a PDF requires asynchronous operation, using `StartDocumentTextDetection`.

Check the documentation:

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/textract/client/detect_document_text.html